# Exporting filterded data from a view to excel

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a requirement, where i have to export data from a list to excel after applying some filter to it.

Say i filter the view by selecting employee dept="Teaching", now i want to export only the filtered rows to excel.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a out of the box feature, which does not include any programming or development whatsoever.

What you have to do, is create a view which filters your data by your requirement. In you case: dept="Teaching".

After this, just export the list to Excel and you end up with your already filtered data.

Comment: I have just given one example where Dept="teaching", But i have plenty of columns, where i need the filter to be applied. Creating a view for every filter doesn't make any sense and its really time consuming.

Comment: So is devloping a custom solution. Why don't you export the whole list and filter it the way you like in Excel?

Comment: Ya, then the only way is to develop a custom solution? And Client want it to be exported to excel as it looks on screen :(

Comment: I honestly can't imagine a way you could do this faster if you write up some code. You haven't given any information on how often you need to export this data, how many filters you need and how many lists are affected eiter on the other hand, so all I do is guessing.
And by that: Using the out of the box features is my best advice

Comment: There are some 5 to 6 lists with each list having 5 to 6 columns to filter. anyways, thanks